# setting up kubernetes cluster and running a database

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cluster

[image: kubernetes cluster]

This is my proposed kubernetes cluster, I want to be able to run Postgresql database, with my nodes accessing storage machine for storing the data, is this using NFS a good option? How best can I run a database instance here?

Comment: I would not use NFS for databases. Also make sure to run a distributed database like https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator or CockroachDB

Comment: Well i am very green to kubernetes I will definately explore that option, and how does crunchy data postgres store the data? on each individual node?

Comment: Its replicated to all nodes, so it does tolerate that a node goes down.

Comment: so sounds like if all nodes participate then one of them is a master, am I still able to specify which folder the data will go?

Comment: You can also have a look at **Rook** https://rook.io/

Comment: Are you trying to use shared volume for all Postgre pod or individual for each one?

Comment: my idea was to save all data to the datastore machine, how that will work with the cluster I have no idea how to configure it

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use helm chart for deploying any kind of data base, it is very handy and easy to deploy, visit the link:
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql

Any way if you want to deploy Postgresql, first of all you need to create persistent volume(pv) and persistent volume claim(pvc), because you choosed NFS for your cluster storage solution. You have to manually create your pv and pvc.

But kubernetes has storage class solution too, it is better to use some kubernetes volume plugin with internal provisioner like glusterfs or cephfs.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/